# Arraylist is not storing values in java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a class in Java in which I am using an array list as a global list

```
public class PolicyRules extends Fragment {

ArrayList<String> application_delegated_scopes_array;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    application_delegated_scopes_array=new ArrayList<>();

    functionToStoreValues();            
}    

}
```

I have a funcion to store values in it. The is a scenaria in function There is a loop in function . On first iteration it stores the value in array list and those stored values and sent to another list like this

```
   private void functionToStoreValues()
   {
           for(int h=0;h<permissionGrants.size();h++)
                    {
                       application_delegated_scopes_array.add(permissionGrants.get(h));
                    }
            if(application_delegated_scopes_array.size()>0)
              {
               applicationPolicy.setDelegatedScopes(application_delegated_scopes_array);
              functionToStoreValues();
            }

}
```

Now when i call function for second time.. logically the values in my arraylist `application_delegated_scopes_array` should be there and on second iteration the values should be added on next position like this
On first iteration the values stores lets say are

```
1
2
3
```

On second iteration the values stores lets say are

```
4
5
6
```

So after two iterations my arraylist will be like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

This is happening perfectly... But this is not what i want. On first iteration the values are stored and frowarded to the next list then i want values in array list should be remove then in next iteration..the new values should be
for this at the end of first iteartion i used 
`.clear()` and `.removerAll()`.  Both of these are clearing the arraylist but my values are stroing again

Comment: Thank you for the description of what you are trying to do. Will you also include a complete code example that we can just copy and paste to run ourselves?

Comment: I entered the only relevent code not extra code

Comment: Also, check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on how to debug your code. These are very helpful in solving problems like the one you describe here.

Comment: Yes, I realize that you are trying to keep the code as small as possible. However, for me to help you, I need to be able to compile and run the code myself. The snippets you provide here are difficult to put together into something that runs. I suggest creating a new class that only has an ArrayList and does the things you are asking about. You should make it so that it runs as a stand-alone Java program without any Android stuff.

Comment: This is my whole code of android class of almost 3000 lines ... I have been tired by searching it....I debugged the code also

Comment: I realize Android code can be very long and complicated. What you are asking about here only involves `ArrayList` and has nothing to do with Android. I suggest you create a new Java class to do just the thing you are asking about. See [mcve] for tips on how to create an example. I find that when I do this, I sometimes solve the problem by myself. Even if I don't, it gives me a complete example that I can post here to ask for help.

Comment: can u help me with team viewer?